# Devtools reloading with spring datasource initialization

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I'm trying to use devtools,but it fails after reload due to data.sql being ran again. I'm using `spring.datasource.initialize=true` to initialize the database. I will probably find a way around, but I want to know how does this devtools behaves around Flyway and data source initialization.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? We made some improvements in this area in 1.3.3. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4699 for details.

Comment: I'm on 1.3.2.RELEASE. Thanks for finding this issue I was unable to describe me problem to Uncle Google properly.

Comment: How should I proceed, if I would like to preserve the DB state between restarts? I.e. preserver data already entered during ongoing development process.

Comment: Use a tool like Flyway, rather than `data.sql`, to populate your database and disable `DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: I'm using flyway, datasource is used only for creating set of users, so I'm able to login in with different roles. Datasource initialization is not used in production. I don't know how to use some profile specific flyway scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Rising the version to 1.3.3.RELEASE does the job. At least for me, as I don't want to preserve the content in DB between restarts.